# Querying jsonb in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb column called authors in my postgresql database table that has data like the following:

```
[{"id":134,"nameKey":"smith, john"},
 {"id":112,"nameKey":"bats, billy"}]
```

How do I return all rows from the table where the jsonb author column contains an author with id 112?

I need somethign like

```
select * from record
where authors -> id = 2
```

I also need to get by name also:

```
select * from gardner_record
where authors -> nameKey like '%john%'
```

I find the postgresql jsonb documentation almost impossible to make sense of.  When I try to select by ID it says I am missing a cast.  When I try to select by name it says the column doesn't exist.

How should I be querying this column?

Comment: Is that an array within jsonb or the jsonb[] type ?

Comment: It was originally text column but I wanted to query it so I change type to jsonb.  Should I have set type jsonb[]?  I am brand new to jsonb and not finding any adequate tutorials

Comment: No that's fine. I think you have to use the containment operator. `@>`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM   record where authors <@ '{"id": 1}'::jsonb` runs without error but doesn't return any results.  I think this is for an object but I have an object array but im not sure how to modify it.  I think I need to use `json_array_elements` but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements`

```
select t.*
    from t cross join jsonb_array_elements(authors) as j
    where j->>'id' = '112'



select t.*
    from t cross join jsonb_array_elements(authors) as j
    where j->>'nameKey' like '%john%'
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3b66499136065a839d64755a1350504a)

Comment: I looked at the demo, it seems to be selecting both elements.

Comment: @AvinKavish : Yes, if one wants to select only the matched element, `select j from ..` can be used. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4e1ef8c8e7db14f2ead3610a940242cc).  But the OP seem to want columns from the table.

Comment: So to clarify, there is no look within operator to write in a where clause without a join? i.e. `where array contains element that matches predicate`